# "Save could not be completed" errors with Eclipse and MySQL Workbench

Tags: eclipse, save, mysql-workbench

I'm having a weird problem saving with Eclipse and MySQL Workbench.  I am using Eclipse Java EE Indigo Service Release 1 and Workbench CE 5.2.24.  My java is version 1.7.0_01.  I am running on a Windows 7-64 machine.

I have some files on a network drive.  If I edit one in Eclipse and try to save it, I get "Save could not be completed" with the reason "The system cannot find the path specified".  Eclipse can successfully edit other files on the same drive.  Also, another version of Eclipse on a different machine (32 bit Java EE Indigo) can edit and save the exact same file that the Eclipse on my laptop cannot save.

If I edit a model using Workbench on the network drive, I can modify the model just fine.  If I try to export the script however, I get the error "Could not save file ".  Failed to create file .KWLQCW". No such file or directory.  I am trying to overwrite an existing script when I do the export.  Again, using Workbench (same version) from another machine can make the modification that the Workbench on my laptop fails to.

I can edit or change both of these files using other editors with no problem.  In fact, when I change do change them, Eclipse requires me to refresh them, but then can't save after editing them.

Both Eclipse and Workbench work just fine if the files are on my C drive.  All of this was working last week and I cannot think of a configuration change I have made to my machine.  I'd be grateful for any advice on debugging this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to try with the most recent MySQL Workbench version (5.2.39). The 5.2.24 version you are using is quite old. You can [download Workbench here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html).

Comment: Thanks.  I need to use Workbench CE as the model files produced by it don't seem to be compatible with this version of Workbench.  Also, I don't think this is a Workbench issue as it also happens in Eclipse and Workbench works fine in other areas.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I seem to have solved this by deleting the parent directory, recreating, and repopulating it.  I can only imagine that the file system got corrupted somehow.

Answer (score 0):

By changing the permission of the file and directory , the issue got resolved